# External USB bluetooth help

Tags: bluetooth, usb-peripherals

Hello I have a android system that I am trying to find out whether I can get USB bluetooth dongles to work on it.

**Device info:**

```
Model number: Telechips m805s tcc8925 NAND v7 board
Android version: 4.0.4 (v0.4 2013-04-11)
Kernel version: 3.0.8-TV Root@ubuntu #171 Wed April 10 22:56:21 oft 2013
Build number: Full_m805_8925-eng 4.0.4 imm76d eng.Root.20121022.190818 test key
```

It has the option for bluetooth in settings.